# Try or install ubuntu 22.04 stuck on black screen with blinking cursor

Tags: boot, live-usb

I am trying to install ubuntu on a 10+ yo pc. It has intel core 2 duo e7500 and 2gb ddr2.

I am not sure if there is any minimum requirements but when i boot into the USB, and click on try ubuntu. the screen goes black with a blinking underscore. I tried ubuntu safe graphics but no luck.

I pressed Alt + Ctrl + F1 (or F2 or F3 or F4) but nothing opens.

Does it have to do with the pc being too old? or is it something else? The bios is really old, so, many features aren't available.

**Note**: I don't have any graphics card installed.